# Whiel trying to connect Android Emulator to MySql Server I am getting - java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException:

Tags: android, server, android-emulator, connection

While trying to connect Android Emulator to MySql Server  I am getting:

> java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.

I am trying to connect my Android Emulator with MySQL server hosting a DB. But it shows above mentioned error.

the specifications:

- Android Studio Version : 4.0 Beta
- MySQL Server: 5.7
- Connector ODBC 8.0.15
- Workbench versio (JFYI) - 6.3

DB Java File:

```
String databaseUrl = "jdbc:mysql://(server IP):3306/" + dataBaseName + "?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC";

String driver = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver;
Class.forName(driver).newInstance();

con = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl, ConstantsFile.DBUSER, ConstantsFile.DBPASS);
//for above i have created user access and granted all privileges in MYSQL.
```

In build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.15'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.15'
    /*compile group: 'com.sun.mail', name: 'javax.mail', version: '1.6.2'*/
    compile 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.2'
    compile 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

Log:

> 2020-04-07 23:26:30.116 11257-11257/com.example.ABC  W/System.err: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
>
> 2020-04-07 23:26:30.117 11257-11257/com.example.ABC  W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)